# Transferring InnoDB database via rsync

Tags: mysql, rsync, innodb

We are in the process of switching to a new RAID array and need to copy our MySQL InnoDB database to the new RAID array while minimizing downtime (50GB database).  I understand that using rsync on a running MySQL database will not produce a usable copy of the database.  However, can I get an exact copy by using rsync on the running database, then completely shutting down mysqld, and running a final rsync?  Are there any possibilities of data corruption in this case, if I ensure that mysql is not running with the final rsync is run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are describing should work, however my advice for backing up any database using a filesystem-level backup is that unless the database vendor has approved procedures for doing otherwise you need to quiesce the database before performing a filesystem-level backup (That means "shut the damn thing down").

What you're doing will take advantage of `rsync`'s delta transfers and effectively copy the "shut down" database in a slightly shorter period of time since it will just be delta-copying the parts that changed.

As with any procedure, before doing this in a production environment you may want to contrive a test case (create a MySQL instance and a DB, back it up, make some changes, shut it down, do your final sync & make sure it works on the cloned box).

Comment: This is exactly what I have done for years. In addition to what you have in your answer, I usually keep innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct at 0 so that the flushing of the InnoDB Buffer Pool is faster. That way, 1 or 2 less rsyncs to worry about and a faster mysql shutdown to accommodate the final rsync. +1 for this !!! BTW Setting innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct is not as necessary for MySQL 5.5 since the InnoDB Buffer Pool flushes better and faster.